# Matlab function with for, if and else

Tags: matlab

I have a variable var0=rand(50,1).
I need to write a function that changes the first 5 lines to 0 and the rest to 1.

Ofcourse, I can simply do this like

```
var0=rand(50,1)
var0(1:5,1)=0
var0(6:end,1)=1
```

However I need to do this by using **one** for, **one** if and **one** else clause.

I tried many ways but can't get it working with for, it and else.
Can someone please help with this fairly basic fuction?

Comment: Why? This is a stupid exercise.

Comment: Why would you set such arbitrary requirements? Is this a homework question?

Comment: I agree this is stupid, but I have to write some functions that are a followup to this. Please help.

Comment: @excaza It's how some people (i.e., idiots) think coding should be taught.  Because apparently recurrence relations that aren't the factorial or Fibonacci sequence are too hard for people.  I've encountered this patronizing pedantry before while tutoring computational courses, argued against it, and told to let it go.  Assignments like this are an insult to the student's intelligence and education.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly a homework problem to which no attempt has been made to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one implementation that meets the requirements:

```
stupidexercise = true;
topborder = 5;

var0 = rand(50,1);
if stupidexercise
    for ii = 1:topborder
        var0(ii, 1) = 0;
    end

    var0((topborder + 1):end, 1) = 1;
else
    spy
end
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, this seems a silly assignment. Your approach is more efficient.

```
var0 = rand(50,1);

for ii = 1:50
    if ii <= 5
        var0(ii) = 0;
    else
        var0(ii) = 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Even though it seems like a minor point considering the silliness of the actual exercise, I just want to point out that it's not good practice to use `i` or `j` as loop variables since they're already reserved for the imaginary unit in MATLAB.

Comment: @mikkola there's an extensive discussion [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) on not using `i` or `j`